# Large doubles/float/numbers

Tags: c++, c, math, numbers

Say I have a huge floating number, say a trillion decimal places out.  Obviously a long double can't hold this.  Let's also assume I have a computer with more than enough memory to hold it.  How do you do something like this?

Comment: Just as an aside: Another solution that I've seen before was to actually create a floating point number class where you specified the mantissa, exponent, and bias. I thought it was a rather creative solution, though I'm not sue how efficient it was in terms of speed or size.

Comment: @user697111: Well, what is your "can't hold" supposed to mean? What does "trillion decimal places out" mean? Does it mean that the mantissa is huge ("trillion decimal places")? Or does it mean that the mantissa can be narrow (say, only 10 or 20 digits), but the exponent is huge, i.e. the that mantissa is trillion decimal places "away"? Can you accept the precision loss if mantissa gets truncated or you need an exact representation? In each case the solution would be potentially different.

Comment: You don't need an algorithm, you need a wonder. Because you'll need about 8 terabytes of RAM to do arithmetic with two numbers that have a trillion significant decimals. :-)

Comment: @Damon: I'm sure such things have been parlayed into American and Japanese government grants.

Comment: Well ok, admitted... the DoD claims to have a supercomputer with 87TB of RAM (and 43k cpu cores), though I would deem the chances of being allowed to burn about 10% of such a computer's resources rather low. It would be interesting if any single core could access that much RAM, too. I'm not sure how architectures at that scale work, but I would not be surprised if each core only had a relatively small (2GB) amount of directly addressable "local" memory.

Comment: @AndreyT, pi or e to the trillionth digit.

Comment: @user: Most such transcendental numbers can be generated as bitstreams or even accessed randomly, and do not need to be stored all at once.

Comment: Read up on Bailey-Borwein-Plouffe. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need [arbitrary-precision arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision).

Answer (score 7):

[Arbitrary-precision math](http://gmplib.org/).

Answer (score 3):

It's easy to say "arbitrary precision arithmetic" (or something similar), but I think it's worth adding that it's difficult to conceive of ways to put numbers anywhere close to this size to use.

Just for example: the current estimates of the size of the universe are somewhere in the vicinity of 150-200 billion light years. At the opposite end of the spectrum, the diameter of a single electron is estimated at a little less than 1 atometer. 1 light year is roughly 9.46x10<sup>15</sup> meters (for simplicity, we'll treat it as 10<sup>16</sup> meters).

So, let's take 1 atometer as our unit, and figure out the size of number for the diameter of the universe in that unit. 10<sup>18</sup> units/meter * 10<sup>16</sup> meters/light year * 10<sup>11</sup> light years/universe diameter = about a 45 digit number to express the diameter of the universe in units of roughly the diameter of an electron.

Even if we went the next step, and expressed it in terms of the theorized size of a superstring, and added a few extra digits just in case the current estimates are off by a couple orders of magnitude, we'd still end up with a number around 65 digits or so.

This means, for example, that if we knew the diameter of the universe to the size of a single superstring, and we wanted to compute something like volume of the universe in terms of superstring diameters, our largest intermediate result would be something like 600-700 digits or so.

Consider another salient point: if you were to program a 64-bit computer running at, say, 10 GHz to do nothing but count -- increment a register once per clock cycle -- it would take roughly 1400 years for it to just cycle through the 64-bit numbers so it wrapped around to 0 again.

The bottom line is that it's *incredibly* difficult to come up with excuses (much less real reasons) to carry out calculations to anywhere close to millions, billions/milliards or trillions/billions of digits. The universe isn't that big, doesn't contain that many atoms, etc.

Comment: You make a point that long precision arithmetic like this is often of little real value. Too often I think people can use ultra high precision like a crutch. The mathematician in me groans when I see someone who cannot bother to do good numerical analysis, because their computer can compute using arbitrary precision arithmetic. That does not make it of NO value though. For example, methods for factoring of huge numbers is of tremendous importance for encryption methods.

Comment: @woodchips: Yes, but 4096 bits is a *huge* RSA key -- much larger than any yet factored. That works out to a little over 1000 decimal digits, not anywhere close to millions or trillions of digits.

Comment: It is all a matter of time. 60 years ago, double precision arithmetic was wild overkill. But then a slide rule was in every shirt pocket too. Before too long, someone will be wondering how to factor numbers that large. Just because YOU do not see a purpose for something from your vantage does not make it worthless.

Comment: I would argue it is a bit of mathematical arrogance to state that nobody ever needs so many digits of precision. Yes, I too can easily fall into that trap, since good numerical analysis will often overcome the need for spare digits. But the fact is, a good reason for computation in extra high precision is simply to check the results one got in double precision. Did I miss something?

Comment: There are other uses for ultra high precision, for example, those who might desire to study the behavior of the digits of various special numbers like pi. As soon as someone states that there is nothing more to be learned by studying something, they will surely be proven wrong.

Comment: @woodchips: Please read what I actually said: I didn't say nobody ever needs to many digits of precision -- I said it was incredibly difficult to justify. So far, however, you haven't shown much in the way of justification though. The only example you've even tried to give is studying digits of Pi, but computing Pi to extreme lengths is typically not done with normal methods. Just for example, study Cary Bloodworth's `Pi AGM FFT`. http://myownlittleworld.com/miscellaneous/computers/pilargetable.html (there are others, but IMO, his is easier to read/study than most).

Comment: @Jerry - Please read what I said more carefully yourself! I myself said that in most cases, high precision arithmetic is usually a crutch, that is is rarely of value. However, that does not make it of no value. All I will say is that as soon as someone claims they know there to be nothing worth doing in an area, they WILL surely be proved wrong. But perhaps you know the truth. Someone always does, or at least is certain they do.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what [logarithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm) were invented for.

Without knowing what you intend to do with the number, it's impossible to accurately say how to represent it.

Comment: logarithms won't buy you any precision, they will just use the dymanic range differently.  For instance, they are great if you want to represent very small probilities which will likely quickly drop below `std::numeric_limits<double>::min()`

Comment: @Chris: And how do we know he needs precision? And how much precision?

Comment: I agree that they are useful in certain situations, but I was just clarifying what logarithms will and won't do.